# Android Studio Project Structure is not listing dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-studio-3.0

I keep my dependencies in an extension called "libraries" and use

```
implementation libraries.appCompat
```

to add them. However, when I open Project Structure window, I can't see them there:

[image: AppCompat is now shown]

But when I add the dependency like this:

```
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2"
```

Voila, it appears [image: ![AppCompat is here]

This prevents me from seeing new versions messages. Is there a way to make fix it ?

Comment: This feels like a limitation in Android Studio. My guess is that you will need to file a feature request.

Comment: Indeed. I wanted to be sure that I'm not missing a checkbox or an option to turn on for this. I'll try to open one ! Thanks.

Comment: Any news on this issue? Could you share the feature request link if you made one? I loved your medium blog post btw!

Comment: This and suggestions are working fine with new project structure dialog ! I'm having other issues with it due to flavors tho, but this approach shouldn't be problematic on AS 3.5 & forward - and thanks for reading it !

Comment: Hi @Mel, I am doing exactly the same on Android Studio 4.1.2, however I can't see the dependencies listed in Project Structure dialog, do you have any idea about why please?Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey @geekShaw, unfortunetally I don't really know what might be the problem. Didn't really encountered this issue since the update last year.